# What was the goal/s of changing the venue and time of Harry's trial?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Harry faces a trial for having committed an act of Underage Magic outside of the confines of Hogwarts. Elements in the Ministry succeed in moving both the venue and the time of the trial at short notice.

**What were their goals in doing so?** Specifically, were they hoping to try Harry [in absentia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_in_absentia) / have him found [in contempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court)? Were they simply trying to undermine his chances of having his *witnesses* in attendance, damaging his prospects of winning the trial?

Comment: Based on Fudges displeasure on seeing Dumbledore make it, it would seem that the goal was that Dumbledore wouldn't make it and then Harry would be left alone, vulnerable and undefended

Comment: Do we know when the time was actually changed? Harry himself seems to arrive on time...

Comment: harry only manages to get there on time because they got to the ministry super early @Skooba and mr weaslys work mate had just found out about the time change right before they got there.

Comment: Same with Dumbledore.... His 3 hour early policy :P

Comment: @Skooba - Harry (and Dumbledore and Arabella Figg) were there hours early. Presumably because they'd been tipped off that something was up. Or just because it's a cheap trick that anyone could have seen coming after 50 years as head of the Wizengamot.

Comment: @Valorum It seems extremely unlikely that they were all tipped off. Harry was there hours early because it was more convenient for him to travel to the Ministry with Arthur Weasley in the morning than for him to travel at any other time of day, especially since the majority of the Order would also be at work at that time. If Arthur had been aware of any potential issues or changes to the time of his hearing, he wouldn't have taken Harry up to his office and sat around waiting, he would have checked that as soon as they arrived.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I mean 'tipped off that *something* was up' rather than 'tipped off that they might move the  trial'. Turning up early is just common sense if you're worried about proceedings.

Comment: @Skooba A wizard is never late. Nor is he early. He arrives precisely when he means to.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Ah yes, but Dumbledore isn't a wizard, he's a *warlock*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't appear that they were going to try Harry in absentia (in his absence). Fudge caustically notes that the Wizengamot has been *waiting* on his arrival.

> *‘Very well,’ said Fudge. ‘**The accused being present – finally – let us
> begin.** Are you ready?’ he called down the row.*

That being the case, it seems likely that the primary aim was **to damage the chances of Albus Dumbledore being able to attend** (note that his message appears to have gone astray)

> *‘Ah,’ said Fudge, who looked thoroughly disconcerted. ‘Dumbledore.
> Yes. **You – er – got our – er – message that the time and – er – place
> of the hearing had been changed, then?’***
>
> ***‘I must have missed it,’** said Dumbledore cheerfully. ‘However, due to a lucky mistake I arrived at the Ministry three hours early, so no harm done.’*

and **to generally discredit Harry** in the eyes of the assembled witches/wizards, demonstrating by his lateness that he doesn't respect the proceedings.

Comment: self answer -1,000!!!

Comment: @Himarm - [Self-answers need love too](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Doesn't this contradict your [other answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153503/64888) in saying it was Dumbledore and not Harry that they wanted to miss the trial? Surely they wanted *both of them* to turn up too late? That was what I understood by plausible deniability inference in the other answer. Which I think is on-point. As for the lateness thing, I don't think the fact they were waiting is conclusive. The appearance of legitimacy is crucial. If they start the trial at 8:00 and give a guilty verdict at 8:05 then it *looks* like a dodgy trial.

Answer (score 10):

### To make Harry miss his trial, thereby giving the Ministry free reign to expel him with no defence as part of their anti-Harry PR campaign.

1. **To get Harry to miss the trial.** I think that trial in absentia is very much what they were aiming for. The trial is at 8am. The Ministry had only attempted to contact Harry earlier that very same morning.

   > “Sorry,” said Harry nervously. “I-I didn’t know the time had changed.”
   >   “That is not the Wizengamot’s fault,” said the voice. “An owl was sent to you **this morning**. Take your seat.”
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 8, The Hearing)*.</sub>

   You don't change a trial at that short notice if you legitimately want the accused to get there. The letter given at unreasonably short notice was just [to allow the Ministry to cover their backsides](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153503/64888). They didn't actually want Harry there. The letter was just an exercise in bureaucracy so that the Ministry can blame Harry for not being at his trial. If they notified him in advance then they can claim that they acted in good faith, even they in fact didn't.

   Since Harry's presence at the trial was *required* by the Ministry they can legitimately argue that he doesn't care much for his education if he can't even be bothered to turn up to his trial.

   > As you have already received an official warning for a previous offence under section 13 of the International Confederation of Wizards’ Statute of Secrecy, we regret to inform you that your presence **is required** at a disciplinary hearing at the Ministry of Magic at 9 a.m. on August 12th.
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 2, A Peck of Owls)*.</sub>

   Harry wouldn't have been there to defend himself. Fudge could've told his own unchallenged version of the story. Harry's expulsion would've been a formality. By the time Harry turned up at 9 the decision would already have been made. Mr Weasley realises this as soon as he hears that the time has changed, which is why he and Harry run down to the courtroom in a blind panic.

   > “Why have they changed the time?” Harry said breathlessly as they hurtled past the Auror cubicles; people poked out their heads and stared as they streaked past. Harry felt as though he had left all his insides back at Perkins’s desk.
   >   “I’ve no idea, but thank goodness we got here so early, **if you’d missed it it would have been catastrophic!**”
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7, The Ministry of Magic)*.</sub>
2. **To get Dumbledore to miss the trial.** I agree that the Ministry wanted Dumbledore to be absent as well. Their strategy seems to have been the same for Dumbledore as it was for Harry. Namely, "send a cursory owl, don't expect them to turn up on time, hold the trial without them". In both cases, the plan went awry. Fudge was unpleasantly surprised to see Dumbledore turn up, just as he was with Harry.
3. **To make Harry look bad to the wider wizarding community.** Harry's trial wasn't just important in terms of kicking Harry out of Hogwarts. It was an attempt to discredit Harry in the minds of the wizarding community. If Harry doesn't even turn up to his trial then that gives the Ministry the opportunity to present him as a reckless criminal in *The Daily Prophet*. This would cause people to doubt his story that Voldemort was back. Hermione thought that they were waiting until after the trial to really lay into Harry.

   > “Well, they’re writing about you as though you’re this deluded, attention-seeking person who thinks he’s a great tragic hero or something...They want to turn you into someone nobody will believe. Fudge is behind it, I’ll bet anything. They want wizards on the street to think you’re just some stupid boy who’s a bit of a joke, who tells ridiculous all stories because he loves being famous and wants to keep it going...They haven’t even reported that you broke the International Statute of Secrecy - we thought they would, it would tie in so well with this image of you as some stupid show-off - **we think they’re biding their time until you’re expelled, then they’re really going to go to town**."
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 4, Number Twelve, Grimmauld Place)*.</sub>

   This suggests a coordinated plan between the Ministry and Prophet to use the trial to tarnish Harry's reputation. Tricking Harry into missing his trial would cast him not only as a trouble-maker and a convicted criminal but as a waster. It makes him look careless. Cue damaging headlines in the morning *Prophet*.
4. **To intimidate Harry should he turn up.** If Harry *should* manage to get the message and attend the trial, the presence of the full Wizengamot is there to unnerve him. Instead of a more informal discussion Harry has to face a full court hearing. Instead of being interviewed by Madame Bones he has to address the full 50-strong Wizengamot. Instead of sitting in the relative comfort of Madame Bones' office he has to sit in a cold and imposing courtroom which hasn't been used for years. Everything from the size of the room to chains on the chair to the gowns of the Wizengamot to the formality of proceedings is meant to scare Harry, should he turn up. The fact that it is trial by Wizengamot is also a surprise to Harry, which only multiplies the intimidation factor. This surprise and (after-the-event) anxiety is reflected by Mr Weasley after the trial.

   > The Wizengamot were filing out.
   >   “Merlin’s beard,” said Mr. Weasley wonderingly, pulling Harry aside to let them all pass, “you were tried by the full court?”
   >   “I think so,” said Harry quietly.
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 9, The Woes of Mrs Weasley)*.</sub>

   As Valorum says, the fact that the full Wizengamot has turned up on time also further discredits Harry, who's the only one who turns up late.
5. **To introduce Harry to the Department of Mysteries.** It's difficult to be too sure on this point. Voldemort and the Death Eaters did eventually try and lure Harry back to the Department of Mysteries. The fact that he'd already been past the black door at the entrance on his way down to the trial eventually proved crucial with Harry working out the true location in his repetitive dreams. Whether the trial was purposefully moved to show Harry the Department is perhaps uncertain. Voldemort was trying to get the prophecy by other means at that point. Luring Harry wasn't yet part of his agenda. On the other hand, senior Death Eaters like Lucius Malfoy were well placed to influence Fudge's agenda, whether by the Imperius Curse or (more likely) by buying access through generous donations.

   > “Mr. Weasley,” said Harry slowly, “if Fudge is meeting Death Eaters like Malfoy, if he’s seeing them alone, how do we know they haven’t put the Imperius Curse on him?”
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 9, The Woes of Mrs Weasley)*.</sub>

   Even if it isn't necessarily likely that the Death Eaters were trying to plant the location of the Department of Mysteries in Harry's mind at this point the thought does at least occur to Mr Weasley.

   > “Those courtrooms haven’t been used in years,” said Mr. Weasley angrily. “I can’t think why they’re doing it down there - **unless** - but no ...”
   >   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7, The Ministry of Magic)*.</sub>

   Knowing the importance of the prophecy and the importance of Harry Mr Weasley briefly wonders whether the Death Eaters might have a secret agenda in moving the hearing venue. Then he discounts the prospect. He was probably wise to do so.

Comment: How much of part five is speculation and how much is just you bragging about your evil plan?

Comment: @ibid I mean really what is the point of having an evil plan if you can't boast about it?